# How to get Date from String in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have save the timestamp in data base like:

```
"NSDate()" // which save Date like this: 2017-03-10 22:53:30 +0000
```

Now i need to get Date from this string, I have tried every format but it's keep returning nil.

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss ZZZ"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    print(dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-03-10 22:53:30 +0000") ?? "No Value") // always return No Value
```

here i have tried so many formats e.g:
    yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss +zzzz
    yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss xx

Have seen many answers but no answer is working on this format of date "2017-03-10 22:53:30 +0000"

Comment: Why are you trying to parse the output of printing an `NSDate`? Never use the output of printing an `NSDate` (or `Date`) except for logging and debugging. The output is not stable. It has changed in the past and it can change again.

Comment: @rmaddy So isn't it a good idea to take current timestamp from NSDate() as well?

Comment: I didn't say that. I'm saying not to convert the `NSDate` to a string using its description. It's not a stable format. And also, since you are using Swift 3, don't even use `NSDate`. Use `Date`. But the same applies. Store the `Date` object itself or convert to a specific format using `DateFormatter`

Comment: @rmaddy Got it, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Military time (24-value hours) uses the capital 'H'. Try this for your formatting String:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
```

Comment: Nitpick - It's just 24-hour time. Just because military time typically uses 24-hour time doesn't mean all 24-hour time is military time (which is usually as `HHmm`).

Comment: I love nitpicks. I'm answering questions, as much to re-inure myself to 'speaking' Swift, after several months off, as anything else. Thank you very much for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

`hh` is a 12-hour hours. You need `HH` if you have a 24-hour hour padding. Check http://nsdateformatter.com for more details about NSDateFormatter formats.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what making me confused, check this screen shot: http://i.imgur.com/ZNafBj5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code while converting `String` to `Date` . 
(**Swift 3**)

```
extension String
{
     func  toDate( dateFormat format  : String) -> Date
    {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: self)
        {
            return date
        }
        print("Invalid arguments ! Returning Current Date . ")
        return Date()
    }
}
```

and just call like . .

```
 print ( "2016-06-20T13:01:46.457+02:00".toDate(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ") )
//Capital HH for 24-Hour Time
```